# Simple Network configuration in datacenter

Tags: switch

My question will seem pretty basic as I am a beginner in network configuration and design

I am about to setup an environment which is from a functional point of view like this:

INTERNET <--->  APP_SERVER (Ip Table) <---> SERVER_1 ;  SERVER_2 ...

So basically there is one server which is able to connect to the internet using an IPv4. Other servers i.e. SERVER_1 to SERVER_N are not reachable from the internet but must be reachable from APP_SERVER.

I am completely lost about what hardware is needed to setup such an environment: the datacenter gave me one IPv4 address and I have one switch (Cisco Catalyst 3500 XL)

Do I have enough equipment? Do i need other things such as a router / firewall etc ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this.  If you want absolutely no internet connectivity from the Internet to Server1/2, then I would put them in a separate VLAN.  The connection would look like this:

```
{Internet}
    |
{Switch - VLAN 10}
    |
[APP Server]
    |
{Switch - VLAN 20}
 |            |
Server1     Server2
```

You can use one physical switch for "in front" and "behind" the App Server, with two different VLANs.  Or you can use two separate physical switches.  Also, the easiest way to cable the above is to use two NIC's on the APP Server, one facing the Upstream (towards the Internet), and the other facing downstream (towards the Server1/2).

If you only have one NIC available, you will have to use a Trunk link to a single switch, which will send both VLANs to your server over one physical connection.  Then you will have to make your APP Server VLAN aware so it can properly segregate traffic going to the Internet or traffic going to Server1/2.

In all cases, you will have a particular IP Network for the "in front" VLAN,  another one for the "behind" VLAN.  The "in front" VLAN's IP will be set by your hosting provider.  The "behind" VLAN can be anything you choose.  I used VLAN#'s 10 and 20 above, but those are arbitrary, they can be anything you like them to be.